# Assign ObservableCollection<T>.NotifiyCollectionChanged Handler to another Observable collection

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, casting, event-handling, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<TEntity>` that is created in class *A* and its NotifyCollectionChanged event is wired to a event handler in static class *B* and passed to class *C*.

In class *C* I use the *Linq* `.Cast` extension method to create a new `ObservableCollection<TInterface>` based on the original.

Is there a way to assign `ObservableCollection<TEntity>.NotifiyCollectionChanged` event handler to `ObservableCollection<TInterface>.NotifiyCollectionChanged`?

Note: This is Silverlight 4 code

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to automatically update one collection when another one changes?

If so [Continous LINQ](http://clinq.codeplex.com/) or [Bindable LINQ](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/) may help you out?

Comment: This looks very interesting indeed, seems like *exactly* what I'm looking for. Investigating now. Thanks, Oli

Comment: just noticed that Bindable LINQ is apparently _dead_ and they themselves recommend [Obtics](http://obtics.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I forgot to mention two things:
1. Its Silverlight 4 code (Oops)
2. I need the destination collection to update the source, both CLinq and Obtics seem to be one way at the moment.